# Grails memory leakage for bulk upload - HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using Quartz job to do some backend processing, which result into bulk upload to database. I am explicitly clearing up the session as given below.

```
class MyService {
    def sessionFactory
    static transactional = false

    def runJob() {
        def collectionOfDomain = []
        for {
            collectionOfDomain.add(someData)
            if(collectionOfDomain.size() == 200) {
                SomeDomain.saveAll(collectionOfDomain)
                sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
                sessionFactory.currentSession.clear()
                collectionOfDomain.clear()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My process runs fine for some instances, and after few successful executions, I see following errors in the logs. I see the same error when I shutdown the server. I am using Grails 2.3.6 and Postgres and Hibernate 3.6.x

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

```
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@45331d5e]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2@1ecd29d0]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [
{DEFAULT=0}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@45331d5e]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2@1ecd29d0]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{DEFAULT=0}
]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@45331d5e]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2@1ecd29d0]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [
{DEFAULT=0}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@45331d5e]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2@1ecd29d0]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{DEFAULT=0}
]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@45331d5e]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2@1ecd29d0]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [
{DEFAULT=0}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@45331d5e]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2@1ecd29d0]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{DEFAULT=0}
]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@45331d5e]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2@1ecd29d0]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [
{DEFAULT=0}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@45331d5e]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 24, 2014 7:27:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2@1ecd29d0]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{DEFAULT=0}
```

Comment: Was this ever resolved?