# Grails memory leak while uploading war file everytime

Tags: tomcat, grails, memory-leaks

I get following error every time I try to undeploy/stop grails application through tomcat manager.

```
Aug 16, 2014 5:32:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/rie] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Aug 16, 2014 5:32:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/rie] appears to have started a thread named [PoolCleaner[1114685649:1408190574406]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I tried going through different forum but did not get correct pointers, any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think I had the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312570/tomcat-grails-memory-leaks.  Might be worth it to post a Jira ticket to the Grails board or at least re-open the ticket that was supposedly fixed.